# Blade syntax in separate js file

Tags: laravel-5.1

I've my `resources/lang/en/validation.php` file. Meanwhile, I can do trans() from javascript block inside *.blade.php view file.

Well, what I'm supposed to do is to place my javascript separately. Then there'll be a new question : What about the blade syntax in it? How can I 'pass' the blade syntax?

Or are there any better solutions/ approaching? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this. Lets prepare the template to declare i18n strings using `@yield('i18n')` entry:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        <script>@yield('i18n')</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @section('sidebar')
            This is the master sidebar.
        @show

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, in your view, you can declare specific strings for this:

```
// login view
@extends('template.master')
@section('i18n')
   var i18n = {
       welcome: '{{ trans("app.welcome") }}',
       bye: '{{ trans("app.bye") }}'
   };
@stop
```

As `var i18n` is declared in the very top of your template you are able to call it inside of each standalone javascript files as `var msg = i18n.welcome;` or `var msg = i18n.bye;`.